# Django: How can I invisibly pass a variable to another template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have three templates in my project—we'll call them **first.html**, **second.html**, **third.html**.

**first.html** gets a string from the user, using an `<input>` tag:

```
<input type="radio" name="selection" value="example_string" />
```

**second.html** displays this string using `{{selection}}`. (In my **views.py**, I got the value using `request.POST.get` and `render_to_response()`.)

The question is: how do I send this value from **second.html** to **third.html**? One of my attempts—using a `<span>` tag to save the information in a variable—is illustrated below, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<span name="selection" value={{selection}}>{{selection}}</span>
```

**Edit:** The following line works by creating a dummy single radio button. I don't know why it shouldn't be possible to create a variable without an `<input>` tag [visible to the user].

```
<input type="radio" name="selected" value={{selected}} checked="checked" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, now that I've found the answer on [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/widgets/).

There's a special kind of `<input>` tag precisely for this: `"hidden"`. The following line accomplishes the same as was asked in the question, but without a dummy element visible to the user:

```
<input type="hidden" name="selected" value={{selected}} />
```

Comment: Your question, after "clarification" is whether this is possible without using an input tag. This is an input tag.

Comment: I didn't know that there was an `<input>` tag that was invisible. I was looking for a way to get the information invisibly, and I found it. It happens to use the same tag as visible elements but is invisible to the user.

Answer (score 5):

You need to understand how the web works: each page is entirely separate, and is requested using a separate request.

Your basic options are: save data on the client side, or post it back to the server.

Both options can be performed with javascript, or posting back can also be performed by posting the form back to the server.

If you want to send it back to the server, it will have to be stored in the current session, or in a model.

There are many javascript libraries. If you want to use them, I suggest you google around the subject.

Comment: So it's not possible to create a variable and pass the value along? I successfully created an `<input>` that passed the variable along via a dummy single radio button. Why is there, then, no support for creating variables outside of `<input>` tags?

Comment: @JohnPeyton I'm really not sure what you're asking. I think you don't understand that just because the code is all on the server, *the web page that your template generates is not the server, it is in the browser*. There is no sharing of "variables" (whatever you mean by that) between browser and server. My answer contains the various ways you can store a value from a web page for access on another page.

Comment: I understand that the data values I want are in the browser. But as I mentioned, I was able to send the new template the data value using a dummy `<input>`. My question is, if I can accomplish this with the `<input>`, is there a way for me to create such a value (available by POST request) without such an `<input>`? No cookies would then be necessary for this kind of simple data.

Comment: @JohnPeyton Yes, as I mention, you can either use a form post (which is what you have done), or you can use javascript to send the value to the server in some other way.

Comment: And is there a method of using a form post that does not require user input? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JohnPeyton Yes, javascript. That said, you don't need to use form post - you can just use a get.